# Iterating results back into an OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl

I have written an openCL kernel that takes 25million points and checks them relative to two lines, (A & B). It then outputs two lists; i.e. set A of all of the points found to be beyond line A, and vice versa.

I'd like to run the kernel repeatedly, updating the input points with each of the line results sets in turn (and also updating the checking line). I'm guessing that reading the two result sets out of the kernel, forming them into arrays and then passing them back in one at a time as inputs is quite a slow solution.

As an alternative, I've tested keeping a global index in the kernel that logs which points relate to which line. This is updated at each line checking cycle. During each iteration, the index for each point in the overall set is switched to 0 (no line), A or B or so forth (i.e. the related line id). In subsequent iterations only points with an index that matches the 'live' set being checked in that cycle (i.e. tagged with A for set A) are tested further.

The problem is that, in each iteration, the kernels still have to check through the full index (i.e. all 25m points) to discover wether or not they are in the 'live' set. As a result, the speed of each cycle does not significantly improve as the size of the results set decrease over time. Again, this seems a slow solution; whilst avoiding passing too much information between GPU and CPU it instead means that a large number of the work items aren't doing very much work at all.

Is there an alternative solution to what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use atomics to sort the outputs into two arrays. Ie if we're in A then get my position by incrementing the A counter and put me into A, and do the same for B

Using global atomics on everything might be horribly slow (fast on amd, slow on nvidia, no idea about other devices) - instead you can use a local atomic_inc in a 0'd local integer to do exactly the same thing (but for only the local set of x work-items), and then at the end do an atomic_add to both global counters based on your local counters

To put this more clearly in code (my explanation is not great)

```
int id;

if(is_a)
    id = atomic_inc(&local_a);
else
    id = atomic_inc(&local_b);

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

__local int a_base, b_base;

int lid = get_local_id(0);

if(lid == 0)
{
    a_base = atomic_add(a_counter, local_a);
    b_base = atomic_add(b_counter, local_b);
}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

if(is_a)
    a_buffer[id + a_base] = data;
else
    b_buffer[id + b_base] = data;
```

This involves faffing around with atomics which are inherently slow, but depending on how quickly your dataset reduces it might be much faster. Additionally if B data is not considered live, you can omit getting the b ids and all the atomics involving b, as well as the write back